# What is the percentage of chance a Tree Ent will spawn when a tree is chopped down?

Tags: dont-starve

When I chop down trees in Don't Starve, I always expect something to attack me like a sudden Tree Ent spawning. I will feel safer if I know when a Tree Ent will spawn. So what's the chance that a Tree Ent will spawn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Treeguard

> Treeguards do not normally spawn before Day 3, after which each
>   Evergreen at any stage fallen has a 1.33% chance of spawning one from
>   a nearby Evergreen tree. After Day 30, up to two Treeguards may spawn at once,
>   with up to three spawning after Day 80 given enough Evergreens nearby.

I assume you meant Treeguards not Tree Ents. You should never feel safe, RNG is never on your side.